# how to modify the operand in this IR

Tags: llvm

%1 = load i32, i32* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.A, %struct.A* @g_a, i64 0, i32 1, i32 2), align 4, !tbaa !10
I want to change the number from i64 0, i32 1, i32 2 to i64 0, i32 0, i32 1

first I get the operand "i32* getelementptr inbounds..." from "%1 = load i32, i32* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.A, %struct.A* @g_a, i64 0, i32 1, i32 2), align 4, !tbaa !10"
then I try to dyn_cast it to GEP, but if failed. "const GetElementPtrInst *gep = dyn_cast(op);"
the gep equal to Nullptr. so I can't get the gep to modify the value.
so how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a load instruction whose second operand is a [constant GEP](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrConstantExpr.html) that in turn has four operands. If you start with an `Instruction * i` that represents the load, then `dyn_cast<GetElementPtrConstantExpr>(i->getOperand(1))` will get you the GEP. You can't call setOperand() on a constant (all users of a constant share the same object) but you can clone it and call [setOperand(1, yourClonedGep)](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html) on the load.

I seem to remember that there is some way to treat GEP constants and GEP instructions using the same code, but I don't remember what it is right now, and I'm afraid I haven't the time to look it up.